# sbt test gives: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class"

Tags: scala, sbt

When I run 'sbt test' I get:
"[error] (test:executeTests) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class"

I'm guessing that I'm running with a particular Scala version and ScalaTest is expecting a different Scala version. However why this happens, I don't know! I think I'm running with Scala 2.11 and that this is also with ScalaTest should be expecting.

Of interest might be that I'm not actually using ScalaTest. I'm only using JUnit tests.

The project can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/keyboardDrummer/ParticleCompiler).
I'm using this sbt file:

```
name := "ParticleCompilerSbt"    
version := "1.0"    
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.fifesoft" % "rsyntaxtextarea" % "2.5.8"    
libraryDependencies += "org.swinglabs" % "swingx" % "1.6.1"    
libraryDependencies += "jgraph" % "jgraph" % "5.13.0.0"    
libraryDependencies += "org.tinyjee.jgraphx" % "jgraphx" % "2.3.0.5"    
libraryDependencies += "org.jgrapht" % "jgrapht-core" % "0.9.1"    
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.0" % "test"    
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"    
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"    
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.8"    
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.5"    
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-swing_2.11" % "2.0.0-M2"    
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-parser-combinators_2.11" % "1.0.4"    
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.5"    
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "18.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.1.3"
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "testResources"
```

'sbt test' gives the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
        at org.scalatest.ConfigMap.<init>(ConfigMap.scala:97)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.parsePropertiesArgsIntoMap(Runner.scala:2219)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.runner(Framework.scala:1026)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$createTestRunners$1.apply(Defaults.scala:547)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$createTestRunners$1.apply(Defaults.scala:541)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.Defaults$.createTestRunners(Defaults.scala:541)
        at sbt.Defaults$.allTestGroupsTask(Defaults.scala:561)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$4.apply(Defaults.scala:424)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$4.apply(Defaults.scala:424)
        at scala.Function9$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function9.scala:35)
        at scala.Function9$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function9.scala:34)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.scalatest.ConfigMap.<init>(ConfigMap.scala:97)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.parsePropertiesArgsIntoMap(Runner.scala:2219)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.runner(Framework.scala:1026)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$createTestRunners$1.apply(Defaults.scala:547)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$createTestRunners$1.apply(Defaults.scala:541)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2.foreach(Map.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.Defaults$.createTestRunners(Defaults.scala:541)
        at sbt.Defaults$.allTestGroupsTask(Defaults.scala:561)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$4.apply(Defaults.scala:424)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$4.apply(Defaults.scala:424)
        at scala.Function9$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function9.scala:35)
        at scala.Function9$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function9.scala:34)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've been stuck with this for a while so thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.1.3"`

You're loading in a dependency depending on scala 2.10. I tried upgrading it to the latest version (2.4.11) but it seems like there were breaking changes which removed the `akka.util.Convert` package. You may need to find where they moved the functionality or write the utility function yourself.

Also for scala dependencies I'd recommend using `%%` instead of `%` and sbt will automatically append the correct scala verion for you. i.e. instead of

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.5"
```

you do

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5"
```

EDIT: I think `ByteStringBuilder` in `akka.util.ByteString` is the replacement.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping. However, I've now removed the akka dependency and still have the same issue. I don't see any other dependencies on Scala 2.10. What's a good way to check if something is pulling in Scala 2.10?

Comment: Perhaps try running `show dependencyClasspath` and search for 2.10.
If you can't find anything and have committed the change to latest master I might be able to clone the repo and take a look.

Comment: With 'show dependencyClasspath' I found it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob Wang, I am facing same issue, I have dependent projects, which still using Scala 2.10, But current project, I am migrating to 2.11.7,  is It possible? if possible how, Please help me. In above, you are saying I should not use 2.10 jars. But in my case I can not remove 2.10 dependent base modules jars.

Comment: It's possible but as far as I can see it's going to be very involved and unfortunately beyond my knowledge. If it's a project where you can modify the source (or send a PR for open source project) I recommend setting it the project you depend on to cross-build across different scala versions. See [SBT cross-build docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html)